# Win api C# Клик с удерживанием

Tags: c#, winapi

Всем привет, нужно на "Чужом" приложении кликнуть на меню. Все хорошо, но меню всплывающие и после увода курсора пропадает, а на C# после клика по координатам вообще еле успевает прогрузиться и тут же пропадает. Я подозреваю нужно либо как-то установить курсор с таймаутом, либо правильно выставить паузу между кликами, Thread.Sleep не подходит.

Comment: Покажите код, что вы сделали.

Comment: Все что я пытался сделать - удалил `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, IntPtr.Zero, MakeLParam(528, 343));
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)MK_LBUTTON, MakeLParam(528, 343));
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, MakeLParam(529, 343));`